# Is there any way of changing 'View All Products' in Top Navigation?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, custom, navigation, toplinks

I'm very new to Magento, so this might be VERY basic...

Using the demo data provided by Magento, the Top Navigation bar includes "Men", "Accessories", "Home & Decor" etc.
Each heading has subcategories, so when you hover over, you get the drop down list.
However, at the top of this list (for example) is "View All Home & Decor" etc.

Is there any way to customise this (or even remove it)? It works okay for some of the headings but "View All Sale" just sounds daft...

[image]

Comment: provide some links or codes. Question is not clear

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the question is unclear... can you clarify? Fabian Blechschmidt who answered (below) understood it completely.

Comment: I think when you ask this question, the picture was not there. weren't it ?

Comment: No that was added later. I'll do that in future. Is that all that was needed?

Comment: the question is unclear of course . Even though you have added that image, I cant see categories that are mentioned in your question. The main part is, it is not at all clear what is ` "View All Products" / "View All Stockists"` in your question, without providing any image or relevant code. @Fabian understood it because, he have lot of experience in magento. Every one here not like so. I hope you understand. So before post, first read your question as a newbie and think whether it is understandable :)

Comment: I didn't add the photo, Fabien did :) But yes, I will make sure that I will add a photo every time. I'm a complete newbie myself :)

Comment: I have now amended the question so hopefully it is clearer. How do I go about getting the question reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link is generated here `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml:66`

To change this, you want to copy this template in your own theme and then remove line 62 to 71

```
if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
    $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
    $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'">';
    $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
    $html .=             $this->__('View All ') . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
    $html .=         '</a>';
    $html .=     '</li>';
    $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: The above answer worked perfectly. Is there any way to customise it so that the drop-down works differently for different menu heading?

ie: if Level 0 Category = "xxx" then...

DO THIS

else...

DO SOMETHING ELSE

Comment: Of course, theoretical you can just check ´$child->getLevel()` if this doesnt work, check the table `catalog_category_entity`, how the level column is named.

Comment: What is the best way of checking '$child->getLevel()'?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `$child->getLevel() >= 0`!? :-)

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you meant now... but I think I didn't make myself clear (again). Is there a way of checking the top name of the Category (ie: level 0)? I would like to have different drop downs for each category.

Comment: yes there is, you can get the path from a category, and load the category a few levels above, but you shouldn't do this. Better use the IDs! Then you don't have to load anything